# how to specify the libstdc++.so.6 to use

Tags: gcc, libraries, linker, cmake

I am trying to compile a program of mine, that needs `C++11` features and a newer version of `boost` than is installed on the target machine. I therefore compiled and installed `gcc 4.9` to some local directory (`/secured/local`) with an in-tree build of all dependencies and the binutils. I then downloaded `boost 1.55` and ran `./boostrap.sh --prefix=/secured/local && ./b4 install` to install boost. Both compilations worked fine and `gcc -std=c++11` also works.

My program is built using cmake with the usual `FindXX.cmake` procedure of finding files. I am running cmake like this:

```
cmake ../source/ -DBOOST_ROOT=/secured/local -DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS='-Wl,-rpath,/secured/local/lib'
```

which successfully finds my new boost installation and the new version of gcc. Compilation and linking both work flawlessly. However, upon execution of my program I am getting the following errors:

```
$ ./surface
./surface: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by ./surface)
./surface: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by ./surface)
./surface: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found (required by ./surface)
./surface: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.19' not found (required by ./surface)
./surface: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found (required by /secured/local/lib/libconfig++.so.9)
./surface: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found (required by /secured/local/lib/libboost_program_options.so.1.55.0)
./surface: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /secured/local/lib/libboost_program_options.so.1.55.0)
./surface: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /secured/local/lib/libboost_program_options.so.1.55.0)
./surface: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /secured/local/lib/libboost_filesystem.so.1.55.0)
./surface: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /secured/local/lib/libboost_regex.so.1.55.0)
./surface: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /secured/local/lib/libboost_regex.so.1.55.0)
./surface: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found (required by /secured/local/lib/libboost_regex.so.1.55.0)
./surface: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /secured/local/lib/libboost_regex.so.1.55.0)
```

Running `objdump` on boost shows

```
objdump -x /secured/local/lib/libboost_program_options.so.1.55.0 | grep stdc++
  NEEDED               libstdc++.so.6
  required from libstdc++.so.6:
```

It appears as if both the boost libs try to use the old `/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6` instead the new one in `/secured/local/lib`. What did I do wrong in my procedure?

Note, that I try to avoid setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` somewhere.

Comment: What distribution, please?

Comment: Some old CentOS with Linux 2.6.18. I do not have root access.

Comment: @janoliver https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726993/g-how-to-specify-preference-of-library-path

Comment: @vfbsilva: As you can see, I am using the `rpath` way of specifying the lib directory - doesn't work. Executing my program with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/secured/local/lib` also doesn't work.

Comment: @janoliver strange, does your user has access rights over the library folder?

Comment: What do you mean? I can read /usr/lib(64), and write to /secured/local.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Installing `gcc` puts a `libstdc++.so.6` into both `$PREXIF/lib` and `$PREFIX/lib64`. Using the latter as `RPATH` for boost and my program solved the issue. Using only the former results in a fall-back to the system `libstdc++.so.6`.